# How to catch a php websocket broken TCP connection exception with Amphp?

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket, amphp

Here is the current WebSocket loop I'm running while the connection is still alive. But after 11 hours of continuous connection, I received an exception

`"exception":"[object] (Amp\\Websocket\\ClosedException(code: 1006): The connection was closed: Client closed the underlying TCP connection at ...`

**How can I check for the closed connection or the exception itself?**, this way I can properly end the script logic without an abrupt failure.

```
     \Amp\Loop::run(function () use ($fn, $st)
        {
            $connection = yield \Amp\Websocket\connect('wss://URL');

            yield $connection->send('{"action":"auth","params":"KEYID"}');
            yield $connection->send('{"action":"subscribe","params":"'.$st.'"}');

            $i = 0;

            while ($message = yield $connection->receive()) 
            {
                $i++;
                $payload = yield $message->buffer();

                $r = $fn($payload, $i);

                if ($r == false) {
                    $connection->close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

I am using this Amphp Websocket: https://github.com/amphp/websocket-client

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution to this by looking for the `ClosedException` and running other tasks after it has been thrown.

```php
\Amp\Loop::run(function () use ($fn, $st)
    {
        try 
        {
            $connection = yield \Amp\Websocket\connect('wss://URL');

            yield $connection->send('{"action":"auth","params":"KEYID"}');
            yield $connection->send('{"action":"subscribe","params":"'.$st.'"}');

            $i = 0;

            while ($message = yield $connection->receive()) 
            {
                $i++;
                $payload = yield $message->buffer();

                $r = $fn($payload, $i);

                if ($r == false) {
                    $connection->close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (\Amp\Websocket\ClosedException $e) 
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }
);
```